# Header of (List of Equations) in Appendix

Tags: spacing, header-footer, appendices

I have used [this method](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=428) to create a list of equations. Now I am putting this list as a chapter in appendix as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}
\setlength{\headheight}{0.75cm}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[EL,OR]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[ER]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[OL]{\leftmark}
}
\fancypagestyle{newfancy}{
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[EL,OR]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[OL]{\rightmark}
}
\pagestyle{newfancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\uppercase{\chaptername \ \thechapter.\ #1}}{}} 
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{ \markright{ \uppercase{\thesection.\ #1}}{}} 
\newcommand{\upperRomannumeral}[1]{\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral#1}}
\newcommand{\lowerromannumeral}[1]{\romannumeral#1\relax}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\listequationsname}{}
\newlistof{myequations}{equ}{\listequationsname}
\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{%
\addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}}
\setlength{\cftmyequationsindent}{1.5em}
\setlength{\cftmyequationsnumwidth}{2.3em}
\renewcommand{\cftequtitlefont}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
\begin{appendix}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\uppercase{ \ \thechapter.\ #1}}{}}
\chapter{Formula Directory}
\chaptermark{Formula Directory}
\label{sec:form}
\listofmyequations
\clearpage
\newpage
\end{appendix}
\end{document}
```

The output looks like:

[image]

Two problems here:

1. The header doesn't appear (although it does in all other chapters, I am using fancy header).
2. The huge spacing between the Chapter name "Formula Directory" and the first entry of this list.

Anybody can help me with these two issues?

Comment: Welcome, out of pure interest, why are you coming here with the question instead of asking on LaTeX Community?

Comment: Your code does not include anything that defines the list of equations, where is it? Can you add it to the question?

Comment: Pardon my ignorance. I am a complete newbie to Latex\Tex. I found this forum via Google and  just added the question here. If it is not the right forum, I can delete it and go to the right place!
P.S I added the list of equations command.

Comment: No no, this is the right place. LaTeX community would have been just as good.

Comment: @Johannes_B: No, here are the real experts :-P

Comment: @HazemSulaiman: The `\cft....` commands and `\newlistof` ... macro desperately need `\usepackage{tocloft}`

Comment: The thing is, my code is really long because it was a template from the university, I posted only what I thought the related packages (clearly they are not!) but as I mentioned before, my knowledge of latex is really limited!

Comment: I see, is there any way around that? Like to force a certain page style?

Comment: I don't know if this is helpful in any way but I also have a chapter called (list of figures) inside the appendix environment. I had the exact same problem with it (big vertical spacing, no header) but the solution was to use:
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\uppercase{ \ \thechapter.\ #1}}{}}
\chapter{List of Figures}
\chaptermark{List of Figures}
\makeatletter
\@starttoc{lof}
\makeatother 
\clearpage
\newpage

Is there a similar solution for the list of equations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were some issues in the MWE code.

I tried to fix some of them.

In my point of view, the `\chapter{...}` should be removed and `\listofmyequations` should be used as defined by `tocloft`'s `\newlistof` macro.

The vertical spacing issue can be corrected with `\cftbeforeequskip` and `\cftafterequskip` as recommended in the `tocloft` manual.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\setlength{\headheight}{0.75cm} % perhaps too large?
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[EL,OR]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[ER]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[OL]{\leftmark}
}
\fancypagestyle{newfancy}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[EL,OR]{\thepage}
  \fancyhead[OL]{\leftmark}
}


\pagestyle{newfancy}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\uppercase{\chaptername \ \thechapter.\ #1}}{}} 
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{ \markright{ \uppercase{\thesection.\ #1}}{}} 
\newcommand{\upperRomannumeral}[1]{\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral#1}}
\newcommand{\lowerromannumeral}[1]{\romannumeral#1\relax}


\newcommand{\listequationsname}{Formula Directory}
\newlistof{myequations}{equ}{\listequationsname}

\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{%
\addcontentsline{equ}{section}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}}
\setlength{\cftmyequationsindent}{1.5em}
\setlength{\cftmyequationsnumwidth}{2.3em}
\renewcommand{\cftequtitlefont}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
\setlength{\cftbeforeequtitleskip}{10pt}
\setlength{\cftafterequtitleskip}{15pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Foo}

\begin{equation}
  E=mc^2 \myequations{Einstein}
\end{equation}

\cleardoublepage
%\markboth{}{}
\appendix
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\uppercase{ \ \thechapter.\ #1}}{}}
\label{sec:form}

\listofmyequations
\clearpage
\blindtext[5]
\end{document}
```

[image]